# why NodeJS express' POST handler not called but RAM rise up?

Tags: node.js, express, request

I'm using NodeJs 8.11.3

I have two applications: the first one provides a simple Express' hello world API, plus some other libraries:

```
// API.js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

var compression = require('compression')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var helmet = require('helmet');
app.use(helmet());
app.use(compression());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true }));



app.post('/', (req, res) => {
        res.send('Hello World!');
        console.log(`SENT in the FIRST PLACE at: ${req.body.event_datetime}, now is ` + new Date().toLocaleString());
});


app.listen(8000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 8000!'))
```

and the second one is the API's client. The client sends a post request where the body is a **JSON object of 3.5MB**.

```
// client.js
const rp = require('request-promise');
function send_stuff(obj) {      
  let options = {
    uri: "http://xxxxx:8000/",
    method: "POST",
    headers: "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
    body: JSON.stringify(obj)
  }
  return rp(options);
}

var fs = require('fs');
const content= fs.readFileSync("./big_file.txt").toString();
(async () => {    
  for (let i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
    send_stuff(
      {
        id: 1,
        field: 1,
        field2: 1,
        big_content: content,
        id_domain: 1,
        event_datetime: new Date().toLocaleString(),
        field3: -1,
        field4: 1
      }).then(r => {           
        console.log('ok');           
      }).catch(err => {           
        console.error("API ERROR");
      });

      //await sleep(500);

  }
})();

function sleep(ms){
   return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms) );
 }
```

There are two things that I cannot understand completely:

1. I cannot see any packet received by API application until the for-loop from the client ends
2. Monitoring API's RAM consumption I noted that rise up until the application starts to process the requests.

Questions:

about **1)**, is it possible that the client cannot send packets because the for-loop is keeping the event-loop frozen?

about **2)** is it possible that API's RAM continues to rise up because packets from the client are actually coming but very slowly, cause of the 3.5MB request body they are trying to send, so the POST handler in the API cannot be called until the packet is complete?

Comment: In your example `console.log` placed after `res.send`, and the `res.send` is some sort of the `return`. Maybe this is first your question. And, looks like, when you make a request, you use asynchronous funcion inside response, thats why your response not been closed. That just my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"1. I cannot see any packet received by API application until the for-loop from the client ends"

The JavaScript interpreter in a browser is implemented as a single thread. What this actually means is that only 1 thing can ever happen at one time in the browser, with other actions or events being queued in what is called the `Execution Stack`.

The `for` loop runs immediately to completion while all your asynchronous operations are started. I see there is a commented portion of `await` in your code. I dont understand why you are using await with `sleep` as it does nothing. `await` works with a promise so its perfect to use with functions that make an API call. When you use `await`, you will `serialize` your async operations to run one after another instead of in parallel.

In your example, it will be something like this:

```
(async () => {    
  for (let i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {

    //THIS IS SERIALIZING send_stuff operation.

    await send_stuff(
      {
        id: 1,
        field: 1,
        field2: 1,
        big_content: content,
        id_domain: 1,
        event_datetime: new Date().toLocaleString(),
        field3: -1,
        field4: 1
      }).then(r => {           
        console.log('ok');           
      }).catch(err => {           
        console.error("API ERROR");
      });

  }
})();
```

By doing so, you should see your backend receiving `POST` calls for every `increment` in for loop.

If you do not want `await`, the `for` loop will be completed before `Execution Stack` picks up `asynchronous calls`. This is because `for` loop will form `current execution context`. You are right, the event loop is frozen for `current execution context`. I suggest reading this to learn more - https://blog.lavrton.com/javascript-loops-how-to-handle-async-await-6252dd3c795

"2. Monitoring API's RAM consumption I noted that rise up until the application starts to process the requests."

It's important to understand what goes behind the scenes with XHR to answer this concern. POST is implemented in the browser as a two-step process. (Mozilla is an exception. They do in 1 step to reduce TAT). In the first step, headers are sent and then the data is sent.  Each of these operations will consume some RAM although it should be minimal. This is much more complicated as it involves caching and there is a difference in how each browser implements handling cookies.

Size of data transmitted becomes immaterial (given you are on good internet connection) unless a restriction is imposed by webserver/server-side code. `content` is serialized to `String` so it becomes a big blob of text. Transmitting huge amount of text to and fro impacts async resolution. GZIP compression can have a marginal impact on the amount of RAM required to compress before sending data and decompressing data after receiving the response.

If you choose to compress your data, expect to see an increase in RAM usage before request is posted to server and similarly expect spike in RAM usage after response is recieved.

Hope this helps.